# How to find envelope (continuous function) of histogram in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a histogram from measured data and I want to find an envelope (a continuous function) of this histogram. What do you suggest? How to do it in python?

```
plot_histogram_of_real_data(file_name='/home/me/data.txt'):
        plt.figure('Histogram of real data')
        data = load_measured_data(file_name)
        n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, 30, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram picture]

Comment: What kind of function?  Piecewise linear? A polynomial?  etc.  This is currently a maths problem; once you know what you want then implementing it shouldn't be too tricky.

Comment: As a side note, it is better to pass `Axes` objects into your function than create them (implicitly) internally.  It greatly aid code re-use http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#coding-styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either fit the data that you get from a histogram using one of several ways:

- Use `numpy.polyfit` for polynomial fits (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)
- Use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` for fitting arbitrary functions

There is also kernel density approximation: `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` which is a standard representation for most statsiticians.

In `seaborn`, you can plot `sns.kdeplot` for a single set of data, and `sns.violinplot` for multiple sets of data. For data which may vary significantly, I would suggest using the Kernel density estimates, rather than fitting some function of your own from histograms.